# I want to build an interactive machine learning system to classify items using as much readily-available software as possible

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I have a complex problem I want to solve with machine learning, but because I'm new to machine learning, I'm going to practice by trying to solve a really simple problem first. The fundamental question is: How much of this can I create by downloading/customising readily available (free or commercial) software?

Imagine a system that understands animals in the zoo. I'll track a few simple characteristics of them: what do they eat? are they nocturnal or diurnal? How do they move (slither, swim, fly, walk, crawl), how many legs do they have? etc. Maybe a dozen attributes per animal and probably all attributes known in the training set.

I want to prime this system with some facts about a bunch of animals and I'll tell it that these are true facts. Then, I basically want to say "OK, I have a new animal" and have it ask me about the animal. Based on what it knows about the data it has, I want it to prioritise questions (i.e., ask the most useful ones first). As it learns about the new animal, I want it to start guessing at the answers. E.g., "Is it nocturnal? I think, with 68% confidence, that it is" and I'll tell it "yes, you're right".

I will want to add new attributes about animals. Maybe whether or not they are predators. Obviously I will have to provide data to start with, but I want the system to be adaptable enough to take on new attributes like this and gradually start to build confidence in its correlations as it acquires data.

An interesting similar system is at 20q.net, which plays "20 questions" and is very good. I'm not trying to play that game, per se, but that's the kind of interactivity I'm looking for. My hard problem will look a bit like the 20 questions problem. There will be hundreds and hundreds of known attributes. Any given 'thing' might have only a few dozen for which the answers are known, and the answers to the other hundreds will simply be unknown. Based on what is known, the system that solves the hard problem will have to select questions to ask get more information.

I've seen Weka and I've even loaded a few data sets into it. Does this seem like the right sort of engine to build my interactive system on? Are there toolkits (Weka or otherwise) that make building such a system straightforward? I.e., how much of this can I just download (or purchase) and customise, and how much am I going to have to build myself?

Comment: I am reasonably knowledgeable about machine learning, and I am skeptical that any off the shelf packages are going to make your problem particularly easy.  The closest well studied problem that I know of is active learning, where the system asks you to label instances rather than features of a particular instance.

Comment: Sounds like you need a decision tree learning. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning

Answer (score 0):

Hello :) Nice to meet you. I'm trying to do something similar.

I have researched the necessary data types required for a program in order to understand, learn and, therefore, ask (to learn some more).

My approach is to teach the program just like a little baby. But a little baby gets bored, distracted and doesn't get it the first time. So a computer program would act the same, until it has the basic tools for understanding, like language.

My current model is this

1. create a (blank) database; -- this database has some tables like : words, sentences, actions etc.
2. create a program that can receive input (sentences); parses the sentences, saves words, tries to **make sense of the sentence** (see python nltk); if the sentence requires output then try to search for output by looking in the database for saved actions. If there are no actions then the program asks the user for the result or hints. If you build a script that searches the answer on the web (good luck) then the program asks the user if it is allowed to look-up the answer online.
   If the program cannot resolve the users' request, then it builds up interest on that request.
3. I'm also trying to create a tree of synapses based on the input-output process. EG: the table of synapses has these fields : 1. id; 2. id_object (more on that later) 3. id_parent (the id of the parent synapse). This would be useful if, say, you would want the program to be multi-tasking and remember the discussions so that you would not have to repeat every command over and over.

For instance: I'll prompt the program to search a "THING" for me and "PERFORM" an "ACTION" with that "THING". This requires RAM-like learning (temporary memory) in order to firstly search for the "THING" and (after and IF it finds it) "PERFORM" the (heh based on the programs' synapses history) best matched "ACTION" that it could find.

This is not an answer to your question because you need to understand databases and nltk before you can continue. This is my concept (or approach) of creating a literally learning machine.

Cheers!